# highlight based on external file search

Tags: vim, highlight

I have two text files, ones is the file I'm currently working, the other is kind of dictionary. What I would like to do is to search the first one using the latter as input. I'd like to highlight all matching lines.

E.g.:

**File1:**

```
I like eggs
I like meat
I don't like eggplant
My mom likes chocolate
I like chocolate too
```

**File2:**

```
meat
chocolate
```

In this example the those lines should be highlighted:

```
I like meat
My mom likes chocolate
I like chocolate too
```

Answer (score 1):

The approach is similar to the answer I've given to your [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13679900/813602): Use `readfile()`, `join()` the lines to a pattern, then use `:match`.

Here's how I would build this interactively on the command-line:

```
:match Search /.*\%(<C-R>=join(readfile('file2'), '\|')<CR>\).*/<CR>
```

Note that this quick one-liner omits error handling, regular expression escaping, etc. In case you need to do this often, I'd suggest you turn this into a custom command, just like I have shown you in the linked answer.